# How to tell whether two NFS mounts are on the same remote filesystem?

Tags: linux, unix, nfs

My Linux-based system displays statistics for NFS-mounted filesystems, something like this:

```
   Remote Path              Mounted-on  Stats
   server1:/some/path/name  /path1      100 GB free
   server2:/other/path/name /path2      100 GB free
   Total:                               200 GB free
```

That works fine.  The problem is when the same filesystem on the NFS server has been mounted twice on my client:

```
   Remote Path              Mounted-on  Stats
   server1:/some/path/name  /path1      100 GB free
   server1:/some/path/name2 /path2      100 GB free
   Total:                               200 GB free
```

`server1`'s `/some/path/name` and `/some/path/name2` are actually on the same filesystem, which has 100 GB free, but I erroneously add them up and report 200 GB free.

Is there any way to detect that they're on the same partition?

Approaches that won't work:

- "Use `statfs()`": `statfs()` returns a `struct statfs`, which has a "file system ID" field, `f_fsid`.  Unfortunately it's undefined and gets zeroed out over NFS.
- "Don't mount the same partion multiple times."  This is outside of my control.
- "Use a heuristic based on available space." The method has to definitively work.  Also, `statfs()` caches its output so it would be difficult to get this right in the face of large data movement.

If there's no solution I'll have to generate a config file in every potential mount point on the server side, but it would be a lot nicer if there was
 some clean way to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: Given your example data, you could `sort -u` (unique) `+0.0 -0.N` (by the first N chars) of Remote Path, OR assuming ':' in server1: is your 'field sep' `sort -t":" -u +0 -1`

Answer (score 0):

I guess if "stat -c %d /mountpoint" do what you want (I cannot test it right now)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read the remote system's shared file systems - using:

```
showmount -e server
```

That will give you the real paths that are being shared. When walking mounts from the remote system, prune them to the common root from the remote system and use that to determine if the mount points are from the same underlying file system.

This doesn't help you in the case that the file systems are separately shared from the same underlying file system.

You could add in a heuristic of checking for the overall file system size and space available, and assuming that if they're the same, and from the same remote server that it's on the same partition mapped to the shortest common path of the mount devices.

None of these help if you share from a loopback mounted file system that looks completely different in form from the others.

It doesn't help you in the case of a server that can be addressed in different names and addresses.